# Многопроцессорность во Flask

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

Есть некоторое веб приложение, построенное на Flask, которое по нажатию кнопки производит некоторое действие, результаты которого заносятся в список. Проблема в том, что это действие является блокирующим вызовом и мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы само приложение не зависало на время исполнения действия.

Вот так выглядит часть, которая отрисовывает результаты:

```
@app.route('/scanning', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def scanner():

    form = DataBaseForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':

        Range = request.form['RANGEFORM']
        ScannedList = scan(Range)

        for u in range(0, len(ScannedList)):

            Record = models.Record()

            Record.ip  =  ScannedList[u][1].psrc
            Record.mac = ScannedList[u][1].hwsrc

            db.session.add(Record)
            db.session.commit()


        return render_template("scanning.html",
            title = 'ARP Scan',
            ScannedList = ScannedList,
            len = len,
            IsScanned = True,
            form = form)

    return render_template("scanning.html",
        title = 'ARP Scan',
        len = len,
        IsScanned = False,
        form = form)
```

Часть, которая показывает историю:

```
@app.route('/history', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def history():    

    Records = models.Record.query.all()
    form = DataBaseForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        Changable_form = models.Record.query.get(request.form['IDFORM'])

        if request.form.get("CHANGEFORM"):

            Changable_form.ip  =  request.form['IPFORM']
            Changable_form.mac =  request.form['MACFORM']

        else:

            db.session.delete(Changable_form)

        db.session.commit()

        Records = models.Record.query.all()

       return render_template("history.html",
            title = 'ARP Scan',
            Records = Records,
            form = form)


    return render_template("history.html",
        title = 'ARP Scan',
        Records = Records,
        form = form)
```

Вопрос: Каким образом можно выделить вычисление действия в отдельный процесс таким образом, чтобы можно было во время вычислений уходить на другую страницу приложения, а при завершении вычислений их результаты сохранялись, чтобы при повторном вхождении на страницу вычислений можно было бы их увидеть? Хотя бы идею.

Comment: [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Comment: если бы еще sse расказали как к celery прикрутить на flask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл примерно такой:

```
import threading


CACHE = {}


def action(id, param):
    result = slow(param)
    CACHE[id].append(result)


def start_action(id, param):
    CACHE[id] = [Threading(target=action, args=(id, param))]
    CACHE[id][0].start()


def get_result(id):
    if CACHE[id][0].is_alive():
        raise Exception('Result not ready')
    result = CACHE[id][1]
    del CACHE[id]
```

На веб строне вы вызываете метод `start_action` переадресовываетесь куда надо, а когда юзер возвращяеться вызываете `get_result`. Все.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в данном примере: 

    CACHE[id] = [Threading(target=hard_function, args=(id, param))]

Параметр hard_function должен быть action?

Comment: да, я поправил уже

Comment: Так себе вариант. В боевом сервере (gunicorn, uwsgi, mod_wsgi и т.п.) веб-приложение запущено на нескольких процессах — один запрос от пользователя может попасть в один процесс, а второй запрос — совсем в другой процесс; иногда каждый имеет несколько потоков, и эти потоки не всегда контролируются питоновым кодом. Кроме того, любой из процессов может быть перезапущен в любой момент. С соответствующими последствиями для словаря `CACHE`. Для подобных вещей специально придумывали Celery.